# How to convert format list to json in output child process nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, child-process

I have an output from running a python script from child process nodejs, and output of python script is array tolist() and i want convert to json with status response like this output array:

```
[
    759864000,
    740308000,
    724748000,
    725208000,
    729592000,
    732272000,
    728356000,
    728452000,
    724544000,
    720584000,
    716880000,
    709264000,
    712784000
]
```

to json with status response like this :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        759864000,
        740308000,
        724748000,
        725208000,
        729592000,
        732272000,
        728356000,
        728452000,
        724544000,
        720584000,
        716880000,
        709264000,
        712784000
    ]
}
```

I have used this method to change to json :

```
coba: async(req, res)=>{
      var spawn = require("child_process").spawn; 
      var process = spawn('python',["./coba.py"]);
      process.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
          console.log(data);  
          // res.send(data.toString()); 
          res.send(JSON.parse(data.toString())); 
          // res.send(JSON.stringify(data.toString())); 
      } ) 
      process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log(`error:${data}`);
      });
       process.stderr.on('close', () => {
          console.log("Closed");
       });},
```

Can you help me with this? thanks..

Comment: I don't understand, that list is already legal JSON, so just parse it, then create a normal JS object `{ status: true, message: "", data: arrayData }` and then use `res.json(...)` (_not_ `res.send`) to get that sent out? Also, **always try/catch JSON.parse** because it can throw, and your server should not crash just because what you thought was JSON turned out to be invalid. Also, if you _really_ want JSON out of a python script, use the [built-in json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) with `json.dumps(...)` to generate guaranteed legal JSON data.

Comment: previously I used try catch JSON.parse and used json.dumps in the python script but the results returned a false message and didn't display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you should try 
`res.json({status: true,
    message: "",
    data}) ;`

instead of:
`res.send(JSON.parse(data.toString()))`